# Data Binding Issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am having a major problem binding my data from TextBox to ViewModel To TextBlock. I have set up my following Xaml Code like so:

```
<Page
x:Class="digiBottle.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding Source=UserProfile}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:digiBottle"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
      DataContext="{Binding Source=UserProfile}">

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="232" Text="{Binding userFirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Text="{Binding userFirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

</Grid>
```

The .cs file I am trying to use as a source is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace digiBottle.Model
```

{
        public class UserProfile : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string userFirstName;
    public string userLastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public DateTime signupTime { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public UserProfile()
    {
        userFirstName = "First Name";
    }


    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    public UserProfile getCopy()
    {
        UserProfile copy = (UserProfile)this.MemberwiseClone();
        return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong when trying to bind my TextBox and TextBlock to userFirstName in the UserProfile.cs Source. ANy help would be a major help!

Thank you

Comment: Is that a Windows Phone issue or Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice here is that your properties (setter) are not raising event change. You need to call RaisePropertyChanged in your properties setter.

I would have written it like

A private field

```
private String _userFirstName;
```

Then in constructor

```
 public UserProfile()
 {
      this._userFirstName = "First Name";
 }
```

With Property raising event

```
public String UserFirstName
{
     get { return this._userFirstName; }
     set  
     {
         this._userFirstName = value;
         this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserFirstName");
     }
}
```

And then in XAML, bind it with property "UserFirstName" with two way binding

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="232" Text="{Binding UserFirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Text="{Binding UserFirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: This answer will do as well. :D

Answer (score 1):

DataBinding can be hard to understand at first.  Please refer to [Data binding for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to get yourself started.

For your code: Here are the fixes you will need:

1. Remember you can only bind to a property.
2. You need to raise the event on the set action.
3. You may need twoway binding on the textbox depending on the actions you want.
4. You need to set the DataContext for both textbox and the textblock.

Here are the changes:

CS

```
public class UserProfile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string user_first_name;
    public String UserFirstName
    {
        get { return user_first_name; }
        set
        {
            user_first_name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserFirstName");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}


public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UserProfile up = new UserProfile();
        this.tb1.DataContext = up;
        this.tb2.DataContext = up;
    }
 }
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UserFirstName}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="14,475,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UserFirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" />
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, Going to take this code for a test drive. It will solve ALL OF MY PROBLEMS!!!! Your amazing!